# Struct and GPU computation in Julia

Tags: struct, julia

Suppose I have the following scheduling sales problem. The data generated are dummies to demonstrate the workings, the actual data are different. Suppose the list C represents the items sold, I want to determine eligible list of items to be sold as shown by set E. It does work in CPU. I am now trying to achieve the same in GPU. I did read CUDA.jl package but couldn't really get an idea to perform sorting using list of struct. In particular, calculation of E in GPU. Please help.

```
using Statistics
using Random
using StatsBase
using OrderedCollections

mutable struct net_condition
    precedence::Array{Int64}; estimated_sale_time::Array{Int64}; revenue::Array{Int64}
end
total_items = 20000
net_info = [net_condition(Int64[],Int64[],Int64[]) for i in 1:total_items] 
for each_item in 1:total_items
    append!(net_info[each_item].revenue, [rand(-100:1000)])
    append!(net_info[each_item].estimated_sale_time, [rand(1:1000)])
    append!(net_info[each_item].precedence, [i for i in sample(1:total_items, rand(1:cld(total_items,30)), replace = false)])
end 

C  = [i for i in sample(1:total_items, rand(1:cld(total_items,30)), replace = false)]
E = [s for s in randperm(total_items) if issubset(Set(net_info[s].precedence),union(Set(C),Set([0,1]))) && net_info[s].revenue[1]>0]
```

Comment: Is it necessary for your application that the length of the precedence array vary randomly?  CUDA prefers to work with fixed length arrays, so to use GPU it's best if you could make `net_info` be a fixed 2-dimensional structure. I doubt you would gain any efficiency from using the GPU unless there is a way to make `net_info` into such an array.

Comment: @Bill thank you very much. Yes, the length of the precedence array varies randomly.